# What WPA projects took place in Boston, Massachusetts Metropolitian area?

Tags: massachusetts, research-guides

My father, Walter Henry Belmont, is listed in the 1940 Boston, Massachusetts, USA Census Record as working (occupation) Laborer, WPA projects.

How can I find what WPA projects he worked on?

---

**Moderator's Note on Privacy Policy**:

Walter was born more than 100 years ago, so this question complies.

> "Massachusetts Births, 1841-1915," database with images, FamilySearch
> (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FXC6-NN1 : 7 December 2017),
> Walter Henry Belmont, 30 Oct 1915, Boston, Massachusetts; citing
> reference ID #p 330, Massachusetts Archives, Boston; FHL microfilm
> 2,409,903.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Your question is a possible dupe of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3946/1006. My answer discusses some of the records for Massachusetts. Also, if your father is not deceased, you should edit out his name. See our help center article https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for the privacy policy for the site.